# Quick specific questions about Electric Motors that I can't find on Internet

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, induction-motor, commutation

I want to talk about induction motors and Universal motors.

1) is the rotor of an Universal Motor a Wound rotor?

2) the induction motor with Wound rotor have commutators?

3) Universal Motor can work with DC or AC current. Can an AC Universal Motor be considered an induction motor? Its stator creates a variable magnetic field that induces magnetic field on rotor.

4) how can DC Universal motor works if the magnetic field that goes from coils to the stator  is constant? 
I think electric current creates magnetic field on the stator, and eletric current goes to the rotor by the brushes, so there will be 2 magnetic fields. But wouldn't they have same polarities? Does commutator has something to do with this?

Comment: http://www.emic-bg.org/files/Electric_Motors___Drives.pdf is a good book with the least amount of math

Answer (score 1):

1. A universal motor has a wound rotor with a commutator. It is essentially a series-connected DC motor.
2. An induction motor with a wound rotor usually has slip-rings. Sometimes, such as when converting to variable frequency drive control, the slip rings are permanently shorted together.
3. No. A universal motor can not be considered to be an induction motor. The rotor is directly powered through the commutator and the stator is connected in series with the rotor.
4. The commutator is connected so that the magnetic field of the rotor remains at a right angle to the magnetic field of the stator. Since the series connection assures that the stator and rotor current reverse at the same instant, the magnetic field relationship does not change with alternating current.